# ¿Como puedo ajustar las celdas de este documento FPDF?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Saludos, estoy intentando ajustar este documento FPDF (El encabezado de cada columna) pero no lo logro, no encuentro donde tengo que ajustar para que me aparezcan una al lado de la otra despues de la 4ta me la lanza para abajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<?php
require('fpdf.php');
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','12345678');
mysqli_select_db($con,'pacientes');


class PDF extends FPDF {
 function Header(){
  $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
  
  //dummy cell to put logo
  //$this->Cell(12,0,'',0,0);
  //is equivalent to:
  $this->Cell(12);
  
  //put logo
  $this->Image('logo-small.png',10,10,10);
  
  $this->Cell(100,10,'Lista de pacientes',0,1);
  
  //dummy cell to give line spacing
  //$this->Cell(0,5,'',0,1);
  //is equivalent to:
  $this->Ln(5);
  $this->SetFont('Arial','B',11);
  
  $this->SetFillColor(180,180,255);
  $this->SetDrawColor(180,180,255);
  $this->Cell(40,5,'Nombre ',1,0,'',true);
  $this->Cell(25,5,'Apellido',1,0,'',true);
  $this->Cell(20,5,'Edad',1,0,'',true);
  $this->Cell(30,5,'Sexo',1,1,'',true);
  $this->Cell(30,5,'Sexo',1,1,'',true);
  $this->Cell(30,5,'Sexo',1,1,'',true);
  $this->Cell(30,5,'Sexo',1,1,'',true);

  
 }
 function Footer(){
  //add table's bottom line
  $this->Cell(190,0,'','T',1,'',true);
  
  //Go to 1.5 cm from bottom
  $this->SetY(-15);
    
  $this->SetFont('Arial','',8);
  
  //width = 0 means the cell is extended up to the right margin
  $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo()." / {pages}",0,0,'C');
 }
}


//A4 width : 219mm
//default margin : 10mm each side
//writable horizontal : 219-(10*2)=189mm

$pdf = new PDF('L','mm',array(600,300)); //use new class

//define new alias for total page numbers
$pdf->AliasNbPages('{pages}');

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true,15);
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(180,180,255);

$query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from datosbasicos");
while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
 $pdf->Cell(40,5,$data['NOM_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['APE_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['EDAD_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['SEX_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['TEL_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['CEL_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['HIS_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['DIR_PAC'],'LR',0);
 $pdf->Cell(25,5,$data['DIR_PAC'],'LR',0);
 
 if($pdf->GetStringWidth($data['email']) > 65){
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',7);
  $pdf->Cell(65,5,$data['email'],'LR',0);
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
 }else{
  $pdf->Cell(65,5,$data['email'],'LR',0);
 }
 $pdf->Cell(60,5,$data['address'],'LR',1);
}














$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Después de la cuarta te aparecen debajo porque así lo especifica el código.

Si te fijas, en las tres primeras llamas a la función `Cell` de la siguiente manera:

```
$this->Cell(40,5,'Nombre ',1,0,'',true);
$this->Cell(25,5,'Apellido',1,0,'',true);
$this->Cell(20,5,'Edad',1,0,'',true);
```

El quinto parámetro indica a donde debe moverse el cursor después de dibujar la celda. `0` indica que debe moverse a la derecha.

En cambio, en las otras tienes un `1`:

```
$this->Cell(30,5,'Sexo',1,1,'',true);
$this->Cell(30,5,'Sexo',1,1,'',true);
$this->Cell(30,5,'Sexo',1,1,'',true);
$this->Cell(30,5,'Sexo',1,1,'',true);
```

El `1` indica que el cursor pase al comienzo de la siguiente linea después de dibujar la celda.

Si quieres que aparezcan una detrás de la otra debes utilizar un `0` en todas.

Puedes encontrar más información sobre FPDF en su [pagina web](http://www.fpdf.org/?lang=es).